# Is there a need to check IsSignedIn and IsInRole as a sign in check

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

Simple enough question, is this enough? or is there a corner case where a user can  end up with some information pointing to not logged in but still with a role of some sort.

```
@if (User.IsInRole(Roles.Administrator))
```

or do I have to do this?

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole(Roles.Administrator))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Roles` will be populated by the membership provider when a user logs in and persisted until their session expires, so just as long as you don't have an administrator role for anonymous users the first check will be enough.

Comment: That's great, and to some extent I assumed as much. But it could as quickly have been  one of those assumptions that could have bitten me in the future hehe.